# Deleting Registry Entry via cmd

Tags: registry

I tried deleting a registry-Entry using cmd.

```
  reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\myProgramm
```

`myProgramm` is my Key. I want to remove this key.

I got this error: `This Registry-Key was not found`. 
How to fix this?

Comment: is it a key or value under run? may be a value

Comment: maybe try REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v myProgrammm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a key value, not a key.

maybe try

```
  REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v myProgramm
```